# Triangle inequality for geodesic distance on groups

Tags: lie-groups, geodesic

Consider $G$ a compact Lie group. I am trying to understand the properties of the geodesic distances on $G$. In particular, if we denote by $|x|$ a geodesic distance induced by the bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$ from $x\in G$ to the identity, is there an analogue of the triangle inequality? By that I mean
$$|y^{-1}x|\leq C(|x|+|y|)$$
for some $C>0$ and all $x,y\in G$. Also, is it true that
$|x^{-1}|=|x|$ for all $x\in G$? These seem like elementary questions, but I can't find any book or  reference that addresses them.

Comment: A Lie group does not come with a distance, which distance function do you choose? When $G$ is compact and connected, the standard choice is to take a bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, I am considering the geodesic distance induced by the bi-invariant Riemannian metric on $G$.

Comment: You should edit your post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Saying "geodesic distance" is not sufficient to characterize the distance function on a Lie group with, say, a bi-invariant metric (note that the latter may not be unique), because the geodesic joining a pair of points may not be unique, and furthermore it may not be minimizing.  The standard approach is to *define* the geodesic distance as the least length of a path joining the two points.  Then of course the triangle inequality is automatically satisfied, by composing the two minimizing paths.  Note that a minimizing path is necessarily a geodesic (by a variational argument).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't see how the triangle inequality, in the way I wrote it, is automatically satisfied. How do you compose the geodesics to $x$ and $y$ to obtain the geodesic to $y^{-1}x$?

Comment: @MathNewbie, this is related not to the group structure but the structure of the Riemannian manifold.  When I wrote that one composes the geodesics, I meant that one runs first along the first geodesic, and then along the second geodesic.  No group product is used here.  The resulting path is not minimizing if it is a broken geodesic, by first variation.

Comment: Sorry, I am having some trouble understanding what you mean... So, the inequality I have written is true for some $C>0$ and every $x,y\in G$? My question is precisely if there is such a way to relate the group product with such distance.

Comment: @MathNewbie, for bi-invariant metrics, multiplication by $y$ (or by $y^{-1}$) is an isometry.  Therefore by the triangle inequality, the inequality you want will be true with $C=1$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!